# Model specification for seasonal ARMA-GARCH model using rugarch

Tags: time-series, arima, garch, seasonality, fourier-transform

TL;DR: I'm trying to find an adequate model for time series data that exhibits multiplicative seasonality and volatility clustering by identifying an ARMA-GARCH-model with Fourier terms using `rugarch::` in `R`.

---

Using `R`, I'm currently trying to identify an adequate model for a [time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/499603/accounting-for-multiplicative-seasonality-by-including-external-regressors-in-ar) that displays multiplicative seasonality as well as heteroscedasticity (volatility clustering):

[image: Plot of the series, ACF and PACF]

In order to do so, I've since learned that fitting an ARMA-GARCH model is the way to go. To find and evaluate the best model, I'm currently working with the `rugarch` package.

My first step is to evaluate whether differencing is necessary to make the series stationary:

```
ndiffs(ts_merged_short)#checking if and how many times the series needs to be differenced
[1] 1 #once

diff <- diff(ts_merged_short, differences = 1) #differencing the original ts once
```

My next step is identifying the ARMA-order, as it has to be incorporated in the GARCH-model later on. I'm using the `auto.arima()` function from the `forecast::` package to automatically identify the best possible parameters. To account for seasonality, I'm incorporating Fourier terms that I identify using the `fourier` function:

```
diff %>%
  auto.arima(trace = TRUE, 
             approximation = T, 
             stepwise = T,  
             seasonal = F, #set to false since the goal is to account for seasonality by incorporating Fourier terms in the model. SARIMA(p, d, q)(P, D, Q)[24] parameters aren't supported by `rugarch`, thus ARMA terms plus adequate external regressors are needed.
             xreg = fourier(diff, K = 5, h = NULL), #K was chosen so that AICc would be as small as possible. the frequency of the ts is 24 so that the biggest possible K would be 12.
             lambda = NULL,
             biasadj = F)

Best model: Regression with ARIMA(3,0,5)            errors 

Series: . 
Regression with ARIMA(3,0,5) errors 

Coefficients:
   ar1     ar2      ar3      ma1      ma2     ma3     ma4      ma5    S1-24     C1-24   S2-24     C2-24    S3-24
1.0777  0.5319  -0.7257  -0.7886  -0.8742  0.4714  0.2755  -0.0158  35.1113  -42.7219  5.0928  -50.6997  -1.2522
s.e.  0.1254  0.2299   0.1134   0.1272   0.1913  0.0611  0.0338   0.0324  15.1030   15.1397  7.8889    7.8865   6.9331
C3-24    S4-24    C4-24    S5-24    C5-24
-13.7789  -1.7416  -1.5330  27.7853  -9.0028
s.e.    6.9313   6.4429   6.4417   5.9976   5.9970

sigma^2 estimated as 20900:  log likelihood=-9657.55
AIC=19353.09   AICc=19353.6   BIC=19454.19
```

Apparently, the differenced times series with Fourier terms as external regressors for seasonality is best modelled by an ARMA(3, 5) model.

As expected, the residuals from this model exhibit volatility clustering and serial correlation:

`checkresiduals` yields

[image]

and

```
Ljung-Box test

data:  Residuals from Regression with ARIMA(3,0,5) errors
Q* = 254.7, df = 30, p-value < 2.2e-16

Model df: 18.   Total lags used: 48
```

Testing for conditional heteroscedasticity in my ts using `archTest` from the `MTS` package further confirms the suspicion that the ts can probably be modelled better by an ARMA-GARCH model.

```
Q(m) of squared series(LM test):  
Test statistic:  801.0283  p-value:  0 
Rank-based Test:  
Test statistic:  4817.784  p-value:  0
```

Thus, the next step is doing just that. I'm starting by setting up the specifications for the model:

```
spec <- ugarchspec(
  variance.model = list(
    garchOrder = c(2, 2), #I've tried a few, starting at (1,1). those yielded the "best" model
    model = "sGARCH",
    submodel = NULL,
    external.regressors = NULL,
    variance.targeting = F),
  mean.model = list(
    armaOrder = c(3, 5), #the parameters previously identified using auto.arima()
    external.regressors = fourier(diff, K = 5, h = NULL), #seasonality in the differenced ts
    distribution.model = "norm")
)
```

Model fitting is next:

```
garch_fit <- ugarchfit(
  spec = spec,
  data = diff,
  solver = "hybrid"
)
```

The result is:

```
*---------------------------------*
*          GARCH Model Fit        *
*---------------------------------*

Conditional Variance Dynamics   
-----------------------------------
GARCH Model : sGARCH(2,2)
Mean Model  : ARFIMA(3,0,5)
Distribution    : norm 

Optimal Parameters
------------------------------------
          Estimate  Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)
mu        0.499999    0.855876   0.584196 0.559088
ar1       1.009506    0.022526  44.814926 0.000000
ar2       0.458184    0.029265  15.656452 0.000000
ar3      -0.621477    0.017387 -35.743473 0.000000
ma1      -0.634433    0.007040 -90.117373 0.000000
ma2      -0.744676    0.019738 -37.728949 0.000000
ma3       0.329059    0.015493  21.239647 0.000000
ma4       0.182138    0.023849   7.637235 0.000000
ma5      -0.025306    0.031025  -0.815664 0.414692
mxreg1   32.227357    3.306690   9.746107 0.000000
mxreg2  -11.217877    3.141959  -3.570345 0.000357
mxreg3  -18.741778    2.250048  -8.329502 0.000000
mxreg4    0.660728    2.584390   0.255661 0.798213
mxreg5    9.519166    1.669838   5.700654 0.000000
mxreg6   -0.443679    1.711427  -0.259245 0.795446
mxreg7   -3.751727    1.545775  -2.427085 0.015221
mxreg8   -6.650868    1.431939  -4.644659 0.000003
mxreg9    5.036256    1.456073   3.458795 0.000543
mxreg10   3.491726    1.348053   2.590199 0.009592
omega   568.774124  139.146080   4.087604 0.000044
alpha1    0.406398    0.034451  11.796341 0.000000
alpha2    0.459873    0.043297  10.621308 0.000000
beta1     0.000093    0.047788   0.001937 0.998455
beta2     0.132637    0.025045   5.296034 0.000000

Robust Standard Errors:
          Estimate  Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)
mu        0.499999    4.551389   0.109856 0.912523
ar1       1.009506    0.050910  19.829083 0.000000
ar2       0.458184    0.070026   6.543074 0.000000
ar3      -0.621477    0.075538  -8.227341 0.000000
ma1      -0.634433    0.024862 -25.518177 0.000000
ma2      -0.744676    0.068422 -10.883619 0.000000
ma3       0.329059    0.080928   4.066091 0.000048
ma4       0.182138    0.069865   2.606997 0.009134
ma5      -0.025306    0.077954  -0.324626 0.745464
mxreg1   32.227357   10.743122   2.999813 0.002701
mxreg2  -11.217877    6.913872  -1.622517 0.104693
mxreg3  -18.741778    7.497623  -2.499696 0.012430
mxreg4    0.660728   10.623432   0.062195 0.950407
mxreg5    9.519166    5.345796   1.780683 0.074964
mxreg6   -0.443679    4.743431  -0.093535 0.925478
mxreg7   -3.751727    4.011590  -0.935222 0.349674
mxreg8   -6.650868    2.884119  -2.306031 0.021109
mxreg9    5.036256    4.686360   1.074663 0.282526
mxreg10   3.491726    1.771315   1.971263 0.048694
omega   568.774124  841.580518   0.675840 0.499142
alpha1    0.406398    0.110226   3.686940 0.000227
alpha2    0.459873    0.153114   3.003476 0.002669
beta1     0.000093    0.115962   0.000798 0.999363
beta2     0.132637    0.042478   3.122455 0.001793

LogLikelihood : -8654.719 

Information Criteria
------------------------------------
                   
Akaike       11.480
Bayes        11.564
Shibata      11.479
Hannan-Quinn 11.511
```

But there still appears to be serial correlation:

```
Weighted Ljung-Box Test on Standardized Residuals
------------------------------------
                         statistic p-value
Lag[1]                       1.918  0.1661
Lag[2*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][23]    39.728  0.0000
Lag[4*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][39]    89.465  0.0000
d.o.f=8
H0 : No serial correlation

Weighted Ljung-Box Test on Standardized Squared Residuals
------------------------------------
                         statistic p-value
Lag[1]                      0.2131  0.6444
Lag[2*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][11]    1.3555  0.9894
Lag[4*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][19]    1.7997  0.9998
d.o.f=4
```

But the ARCH-processes in the ts seem to have been adequately captured:

```
Weighted ARCH LM Tests
------------------------------------
            Statistic Shape Scale P-Value
ARCH Lag[5]    0.4885 0.500 2.000  0.4846
ARCH Lag[7]    0.6213 1.473 1.746  0.8640
ARCH Lag[9]    0.6833 2.402 1.619  0.9686

Nyblom stability test
------------------------------------
Joint Statistic:  no.parameters>20 (not available)
Individual Statistics:               
mu      0.15712
ar1     0.15680
ar2     0.02499
ar3     0.14805
ma1     0.09609
ma2     0.07203
ma3     0.14563
ma4     0.12195
ma5     0.19351
mxreg1  0.12802
mxreg2  0.15114
mxreg3  0.10752
mxreg4  0.38436
mxreg5  0.35351
mxreg6  0.14108
mxreg7  0.24750
mxreg8  0.15062
mxreg9  0.18939
mxreg10 0.13833
omega   0.18842
alpha1  7.31236
alpha2  3.54458
beta1   4.56446
beta2   6.37310

Asymptotic Critical Values (10% 5% 1%)
Individual Statistic:    0.35 0.47 0.75

Sign Bias Test
------------------------------------
                   t-value   prob sig
Sign Bias           1.5246 0.1276    
Negative Sign Bias  0.4268 0.6696    
Positive Sign Bias  0.9968 0.3190    
Joint Effect        2.6684 0.4456
```

Furthermore, the empirical distribution of the standardised residuals doesn't seem to match the theoretical one:

```
Adjusted Pearson Goodness-of-Fit Test:
------------------------------------
  group statistic p-value(g-1)
1    20     206.9    1.445e-33
2    30     226.6    1.671e-32
3    40     246.6    5.843e-32
4    50     256.5    6.675e-30


Elapsed time : 15.44052
```

An optical inspection of the residuals of the ARMA-GARCH(3, 5)(2, 2)-model also leads me to the conclusion that the model is inadequate. In fact, the residual plot doesn't appear to have changed much in comparison to the original ARMA-model.

[image]

I've now read a lot of websites and Stack Overflow and Cross Validated questions but I still can't figure out where I went wrong. Can any of you identify my mistake?